# Unmerge a git branch, keeping post-merge commits

Tags: git, git-merge

Say there are two branches `master` and `branchA`.

I work on `master`, a friend on `branchA`. 
Once things are finalized, we merge `branchA` with `master`.

After several commits on the merged `master`, the client wants the 
work done on `branchA` removed, but **NOT the commits done after the merge**.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Read through [Pro Git - Undoing Merges](https://web.archive.org/web/20120411131029/http://progit.org/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html).

Basically, you `git revert` the merge commit:

```
git revert -m 1 hash_of_merge_commit
```

You may end up with some conflicts that you'll have to manually unmerge, just like when merging normally.

Additional links:

1. [Git SCM - Undoing Merges](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325012437/http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html)
2. [Git Ready - Rolling back changes with revert](https://web.archive.org/web/20140216143915/http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/16/rolling-back-changes-with-revert.html)

Comment: please re-read the question, if possible give an objective answer.

Comment: Please re-read the answer, and the article linked. It explains, objectively, how to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ sounds like useful intel but the links are all broken; do you have a newer version of that Undoing Mergest post?

Comment: @DanielThompson https://web.archive.org/web/20150325012437/http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html, or https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things